# IEEE Xplore's Python Software Development Kit returns ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'

Tags: python, nlp, importerror, ieee

I am working on a Plagiarism Detector using Python and NLP and I wanted to build the training set dynamically. Hence I am trying to use the IEEE Xplore's Python Software Development Kit to gather some part of the training data, but when I try to import the SDK I get an Import error.(Exact error: ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe')

I was using the code provided in the [documentation](https://developer.ieee.org/Python_Software_Development_Kit)

The Code(I have replaced the access key and query with placeholders):

```
import xplore
query = xplore.xploreapi.XPLORE('api_access_key')
query.abstractText('query')
data = query.callAPI()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the package available on the [IEEE Xplore website](https://developer.ieee.org/files/xplore-python-sdk.zip) instead of the one available on pip. Use Python 2 instead of Python 3